# Stretching Div Content

Tags: html, css

How can I "stretch" a div?

For example, look at the left side button groups. How can I make that
[image]

into something like this:
[image]

(Yes I really want it to S---T---R---E---T---C---H!!!)

Is this possible using CSS only?

Comment: @davidpauljunior what code should I show? I don't even know if it's possible in css. I'm looking for a generic, 'stretch-width'... (as in any div, any content)

Comment: I presumed their was some code for your first image and you were struggling to achieve the second image.

Comment: What about using a background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to display the div in 100% width thats possible but if u are talking about stretching the text - font , i dont think if can be done using only CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strech font,this is your answer : [font-stretch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch)

Comment: Yupe bt i am talking about the browser not CSS versions.. most popular google chrome doesn't support it.. as far as i got only FF 9+ and IE 9+ support it